# Embedding Swing components in JavaHelp pages in an OSGi environment?

Tags: osgi, javahelp

JavaHelp is a library written by Sun that displays HTML help pages in a Swing application. JavaHelp allows embedding Swing components into its HTML pages:

```
<html>
<object classid="java:javax.swing.JButton">
   <param name="text" value="Wow, a Swing component in HTML HTML!">
</object>
</html>
```

This is discussed further here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-0913/dev/lwcomp.html

I am running a large OSGi application in Apache Felix. As shown above, the `classid` attribute refers to the FQN of the Swing component class I want to embed. I would like this to refer to a Swing component class that I have defined in my own bundle. Because JavaHelp is running in its own bundle, it cannot refer to the class in my bundle. I just see `??` in the HTML page, indicating that the class cannot be found. How can I get the JavaHelp bundle to refer to the class in my bundle?

Comment: I suspect that this will be a painful experience, as I *think* that JavaHelp just does a Class.forName. You'll have to resort to Dynamic-Import, and I don't know if that is worth it.

Comment: Would that entail modifying the JavaHelp jar to include the `Dynamic-PackageImport` entry in the manifest, then using the `dynamic-import` command in Felix? Or is there an easier way to do this? I found that `dynamic-import` causes other bundles to stop mysteriously. And still JavaHelp was unable to find my classes.

Comment: Also, it turns out the real culprit isn't even in JavaHelp but in `HTMLEditorKit`'s `ObjectView`: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/text/html/ObjectView.java#ObjectView

Answer (score 2):

This is only partially possible. Here's why.

To fix this issue, we have to create our own `HTMLEditorKit` that intercepts `object` tags, then create the `Component` ourselves from the `object` tag's `classid`. Here's how that looks*.

```
public class OurHTMLEditorKit extends HTMLEditorKit {
    public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
        return new HTMLEditorKit.HTMLFactory() {
            public View create(Element elem) {
                if (elem.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("object"))
                    return new InternalObjectView(elem);
                else
                    return super.create(elem);
            }
        };
    }
}

private static Object attemptToGetClass(final String className) {
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(className);
        Object o = c.newInstance();
        return o;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}


private static class InternalObjectView extends ObjectView {
    public InternalObjectView(Element elem) {
        super(elem);
        logger.info(elem.toString());
    }

    protected Component createComponent() {
        AttributeSet attrs = getElement().getAttributes();
        String classname = ((String) attrs.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.CLASSID)).trim();
        try {
            Component comp = (Component) attemptToGetClass(classname);
            setParameters(comp, attrs);
            return comp;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn(e.getMessage());
        }
        return getUnloadableRepresentation();
    }

    // Copied from javax.swing.text.html.ObjectView with modifications to how exceptions are reported

    Component getUnloadableRepresentation() {
        Component comp = new JLabel("??");
        comp.setForeground(Color.red);
        return comp;
    }

    private void setParameters(Component comp, AttributeSet attr) {
        Class k = comp.getClass();
        BeanInfo bi;
        try {
            bi = Introspector.getBeanInfo(k);
        } catch (IntrospectionException ex) {
            logger.warn("introspector failed, ex: "+ex);
            return;             // quit for now
        }
        PropertyDescriptor props[] = bi.getPropertyDescriptors();
        for (int i=0; i < props.length; i++) {
            //      System.err.println("checking on props[i]: "+props[i].getName());
            Object v = attr.getAttribute(props[i].getName());
            if (v instanceof String) {
                // found a property parameter
                String value = (String) v;
                Method writer = props[i].getWriteMethod();
                if (writer == null) {
                    // read-only property. ignore
                    return;     // for now
                }
                Class[] params = writer.getParameterTypes();
                if (params.length != 1) {
                    // zero or more than one argument, ignore
                    return;     // for now
                }
                Object [] args = { value };
                try {
                    writer.invoke(comp, args);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    logger.warn("Invocation failed: " + ex.getMessage());
                    // invocation code
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

But with JavaHelp, it's not possible to register our `HTMLEditorKit` using the `<viewregistry>` tag [2]. Because of the OSGi environment, JavaHelp cannot access our `HTMLEditorKit`**.

Instead, the only possible way is to create a `JEditorPane` with our `HTMLEditorKit`, create our own TOC `JTree` by using `TOCView.parse()`, and tell the `JEditorPane` to load help pages when the `JTree`'s selection changes.

---

*This seems long, but most of the code is copied from `javax.swing.text.html.ObjectView` [1]. I had to copy code from there because `getUnloadableRepresentation` and `setParameters` are private, not protected.

**This might be possible due to the `Dynamic-ImportPackage` manifest entry [3]. But this requires jumping through a lot of hoops. First, the JavaHelp manifest would have to be changed. Second, after Felix has started, it has to be told to allow dynamic importing using the `dynamic-import` command.

1. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/text/html/ObjectView.java#ObjectView
2. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-0913/author/helpset.html#toolbar
3. http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/DynamicImport-Package